# How to add 1 to the Text of a Tab in every time on click on a button? in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, tabs

i have a `TabPane` and `Button` once on click on this button should add a new Tab to the TabPane like: `Tab1` for the second time on click on the button should add another tab to the TabPane like: `Tab2`. So while clicking on this button should add `1` to the text of the Tab in every time. 
this is my code:

```
 butser.setOnAction( new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()  {
    @Override
    public void handle( ActionEvent event )
    {
        int hu = 0 ;
        Tab tab = new Tab( "Tab" + hu);
        tabs.getTabs().add( tab  );

    }
} );
```

How i can do that in javafx and thank you soooo much :)

Comment: Can you show the code you have so far?

Comment: @UlukBiy done! i've updated

Comment: @MadPro The declaration for `hu` should be outside the  handle method, you may declare it as an instance variable, as shown by @uluk in his example.

Comment: Your code differs from mine in the asnwer below. Try to understand the code and adapt it to yours. Do you have any problems now?

Comment: aww it works thank youuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu ssssoooooooo muchhh !! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
private int lastNumber = 0;


@Override
public void start( Stage stage )
{
    TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
    Button b = new Button( "add" );
    b.setOnAction( new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
    {
        @Override
        public void handle( ActionEvent event )
        {
            Tab tab = new Tab( "Tab" + lastNumber );
            tabPane.getTabs().add( tab );
            lastNumber++;
        }
    } );

    Scene scene = new Scene( new VBox( b, tabPane ), 200, 100 );
    stage.setScene( scene );
    stage.show();
}
```

Comment: @ Uluk Biy Sorry but this code add just 1 to all the tabs if i click on the button many times the tabs still show "Tab1" :( i want it show in every time i click the button show new tab like : onClick "Tab1" onClick for the second time "Tab2" onClick for the third time "Tab3" like that

Comment: Can you update your question with final state of your tried code.